# Question regarding application approval

Tags: iphone

i have two questions

1. Apple says there should not be any button or menu item which is not yet implemented. In my application in home screen, i have put one button and background image which feels like there are other 3 inactive buttons(greyed) though those are not active ones. I did this to show steps in application. Is that ok?
2. I have used core location and other server access. There are methods for example

   - (void)locationError:(NSError *)error; 
     for core location and NSURLConnections's error method. My application simply shows view which pops up when there is no connectivity(with my server)Is that ok.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Its perfectly fine. You have a defined flow which doesnt confuse the user's. All the active buttons should be able to perform some action.

2) Its perfectly fine to display valid error messages to user's. Infact its a recommended practice.

PS: Finally it depends on the reviewer, but they give reasons if they reject the app and you can always appeal with your explanation. Be sure you mention about the functionality in the review notes.

Comment: for question 2, is it ok to show a view telling network inactivity for location method as well? like in - (void)locationError:(NSError *)error{
    
} this method wot should i write in my code? empty?

Comment: You can always display a alert view with a descriptive error.